# How to download text in async storage into a text file using expo filesystem?

Tags: react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I have some text stored in async storage. How do I use Expo Filesystem to download that text into a .txt file?
Can you give expo filesystem bytes or a string to save to a file instead of a remote url?

Answer (score 0):

`FileSystem` from `'expo-file-system'` does allow you to write a file by only defining it's text and the path you want to save your file like this

```
await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(filePath, text);
```

where text is what you saved on your async storage and filePath is the path where you want to save it and the path would be something like this const filePath = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}myText.txt`;

You can see this from it's [github code](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/400de72306a91c738c6ad0aad238b45b51a1a92a/packages/expo-file-system/src/FileSystem.ts#L99-L108) or just check it's [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemwriteasstringasyncfileuri-contents-options)